# Morphia subclasses [MONGO]

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

So basically I'm trying to create a settings manager for users. Once I save the class in MongoDB and then redirect to another sector it throws an error similar to this - http://hastebin.com/isenakibaj.java (Error). I'm using the class loader from the Plugin class. This works fine on the server with the class 'HubSettings', that extends 'SettingsEntry', but when I change server to one without the HubSettings class as it has no intention to use it (different build) it doesn't like it.

Comment: Show your source code

Answer (score 0):

Morphia stores the class type as part of the document.  When you try to load that document, morphia tries to load that class when loading documents from the database.  you'll either need to tweak the data in your database or make that class avaiable at runtime.

Comment: Anyway to make it not do that?

Comment: as I mentioned, update the documents in the database or make that class available at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean, update the documents because I need the data to be there. I cannot just remove it? :/

Comment: the part that says `className` you change to have the value of the class you want to load at runtime.

Comment: Would making it an @Entity and not store the class name do the trick?